# How i can build old Android project in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

i have to build this project but getting error because it is so old.
[here is the project git hub link](https://github.com/klinker-apps/Android-SlidingEmojiKeyboard)
i am using latest android studio version

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

- Change gradle version in `build.gradle` , change the version in the following line in the file: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'`.
- In the file `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`, update the gradle version in this line: `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip` . Sync the project again, it should work. If it doesn't restart android studio again. It should build successfully afterward.

PS: See what gradle version you use according to your android studio version.

Comment: Change gradle version to what version?

Comment: What Android version are you using?

Comment: if you mean my android studio version : Android Studio 4.0.2 , built on September 9, 2020   ................... if you mean target android version for this app , it should work on android 8 and above

Comment: i have changed build.gradle gradle version to 3.0.1 and wrapper to 4.1 but still not working

Comment: there is problem with repositories to find build tools gradle 2.2.3 , i have tried to add jcenter() and some other repositories but still studio couldn't find 2.2.3 , i even tried to download it offline and add it to studio but its not available on gradle.org , i have downloaded gradle 2.14.1-all.zip which mentioned in project original wrapper.properties and tried to add it to project offline and got this error . no cached version of build tools 2.2.3 found